# What does it mean when least squares and instrumental variables give similar results?

Tags: least-squares, similarities, instrumental-variables

What can said when for some data set the result of a least squares regression is extremely close to the result of an instrumental variable regression?

Comment: (1) There is no significant bias caused by endogeneity in your sample or (2) your instruments are invalid and aren't doing anything to correct for the endogeneity bias.